# secured and unsecured Kafka Clusters on the same cmak instance

Tags: apache-kafka

We have been using kafkamanager for a while and planning to get CMAK. At the same time we are also exploring secured Kafka Clusters (SASL).
Is it possible to have both secured and plaintext Kafka Clusters on the same CMAK instance? or we need to get different CMAK instances?

Thank you

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "get CMAK"... KafkaManager was simply renamed. They therefore work the same way

Comment: yeah, its just new version of Kafkamanager. We never had secure Kafka Clusters earlier, we just started exploring secure clusters. and I was told we can't have both secure and plaintext Kafka Clusters on the same kafkamanager. So trying to understand why that's the case if its true

Comment: Haven't tried, but I would guess it would require adding JVM keystore/truststore properties to CMAK, but those are bypassed for a plaintext cluster, so I would think having at least one secure cluster being added would work with several unsecured

Comment: got it , thanks! will explore and update here